# How to handle this kind of not found error in iron-router?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

For example, I have a `Posts` collection, which has `userId` indicates this post belongs to whom.

And I have a route like this:

```
Router.route('/:username/posts', {
    waitOn: function(){
        return Meteor.subscribe('posts', username);  // A
        // var user = Meteor.users.find({username: username}); //B
        // if(user) {
        //     return Meteor.subscribe('posts', user._id);
        // } else {
        //     return null; // ???
        // }
    }
});
```

And publish

```
Meteor.publish("posts", function(userId){       // C
    check(userId, String);
    return Posts.find({userId: userId});
});

Meteor.publish("posts", function(username){       // D
    check(username, String);
    if(user) {
         return Posts.find({userId: user._id});
    } else {
         return null; // ???
    }
});
```

I'm confused how to handle like `GET /notexistusername/posts` ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure a *notFoundTemplate* for iron-router either globally or on a per-route basis.

Globally:

```
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'layout',
  notFoundTemplate: 'notFound',
  loadingTemplate: 'loading'
});
```

In a specific route (also I've cleaned up your route code):

```
Router.route('/:username/posts', {
  notFoundTemplate: 'notFound',
  data: function(){
    var userId = Meteor.users.find({ username: this.params.username })._id;
    return Posts.find({ userId: userId });
  }, 
  waitOn: function(){
    var userId = Meteor.users.find({ username: this.params.username })._id;
    return Meteor.subscribe('posts', userId);
  }
});
```

Your *notFound* template would typically be your 404 page.

Also you can simplify your publication to:

```
Meteor.publish("posts", function(username){
  check(username, String);
  return Posts.find({username: username});
});
```

Since if there are no matches the find will return a null cursor and that will tell the route there's no data.

Comment: I store the userId in Post not username, I need to translate username to userid

Comment: Changed answer to handle the indirect lookup.